# Prove the differentiability of an inverse function, by the theorem of Caratheodory.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, inverse

The exact statement I am looking forward to prove is that:

> **Theorem**
>   Let $f \colon (a,b) \to (c,d)$ admit an inverse $g \colon (c,d) \to (a,b)$.
>   If $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(m) \neq 0$ for $m \in (a,b)$ then $g$ is differentiable at $f(m)$ and $g'(f(m)) = 1/f'(m)$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuD0V.png).)

---

**My try**: By the theorem of Caratheodory, there exists a function $\phi:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$, $$f(x)-f(m)=\phi(x)(x-m)$$ continuous at $x=m$.

So since range of $g(x)$ is the domain of $f(x)$, $x\to g(x)$ gives$$f(g(x))-f(m)=\phi(g(x))(g(x)-m)$$$$x-f(m)=\phi(g(x))(g(x)-m)$$
For $x\neq f(m)$, $$\frac{x-f(m)}{g(x)-m}=\phi(g(x))$$ 
Now, in RHS, $\phi(x)$ is continuous at $x=m$. And the limit of the expression in the LHS gives the reciprocal of derivative of $g(x)$, but to take limits on both sides, I should first know that $g(x)$ is continuous. So how do I prove that?

Please don't post new methods to prove the theorem, I am looking forward to prove by the above method only.

Comment: The continuity of the inverse function is a different task that should be faced before working with derivatives. In general topology this requires some precise assumptions, but for functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ it follows from a monotonicity argument.

Comment: @Siminore, please help if you know anything about it. I know absolutely nothing about topology. And also, I am just a beginner at rigorous real analysis.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: This is not a straightforward proof for a beginner. It might be easier to assume that the derivative is continuous and prove using this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on a deeper result known as Darboux’s theorem (an intermediate value theorem for derivatives) which states that for all
$x,y \in (a,b)$ and for all $g \in [f'(x),f'(y)]$ (swapping order as necessary) there is
some $z \in (x,y)$ such that $f'(z) = g$.

In particular, we must have $f'((a,b)) \subset (-\infty,0)$ or $f'((a,b)) \subset (0, \infty)$ (where $f'((a,b)) = \{ f'(x) | s \in (a,b) \}$ because if not, we would have
$f'(m) = 0$ for some $m \in (a,b)$.

Hence $f$ is continuous and strictly monotonic. It is straightforward to prove that $f$ is locally invertible and that the inverse is continuous.

**Aside**: While the idea is appealing, just having $f'(m) \neq 0$ for a specific
point is not sufficient to guarantee local invertibility. For example,
take $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x + x^2 \sin { 1\over x}$. Then $f'(0) = {1 \over 2} > 0$, but since $f'$ takes both positive & negative values arbitrarily close to $0$ it cannot be monotonic near $0$ and hence does not have a local inverse.

Comment: But the statement the OP wants to prove is simply the differentiation rule for the inverse function. This is rather elementary, since the existence of the inverse $g$ is an assumption. The OP only needs thw continuity of $g$!

Comment: I don't understand what your point is - all I have done above is to establish that $g$ is continuous via monotony?

Comment: The proof of the continuity of $g$ is totally elementary in the sense that derivatives are not involved. Monotonicity of course is involved.

Comment: Perhaps it is 'totally elementary' to you but it is not clear to me how to establish monotonicity without an argument similar to above.

Comment: @Siminore: Can you elaborate on your 'totally elementary' comment please? I can show that if $f$ is not monotonic then it has a local extremum. However, while the result is geometrically evident and the proof is elementary in the sense that just involves enumerating most orderings of four points, it is far from straightforward for someone just starting with real analysis. If you have a straightforward proof that does not involve something like Darboux's theorem or an enumeration I would be very interested in seeing it.

Comment: I teach the proof of the continuity of the inverse function on intervals in my first-year course of analysis. It may be long, but it does not involve differentiation. As you know, it is based on a characterization of strict monotonicity, and makes use of the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions. I do not know if it is straightforward, but it should be learned before derivatives, in a university program.

Comment: @Siminore: How do you establish strict monotonicity of $f$? That is the key to they whole problem.

Comment: I suspect there is only one way, by excluding all the remaining possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma.** If $f\!:\ ]a,b[\>\to{\mathbb R}$ is continuous and injective then $f$ is strictly monotone.

*Proof.* Consider two pairs of points $x<y$ and $u<v$ in $\>]a,b[\>$. Then
$$(1-t)x+ t u< (1-t) y+t v\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
Therefore the auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl((1-t)y+tv\bigr)-f\bigl((1-t)x+t u\bigr)\qquad (0\leq t\leq1)$$
is never $0$ on the $t$-interval $[0,1]$. Since $\phi$ is continuous it follows that the values $\phi(0)=f(y)-f(x)$ and $\phi(1)=f(v)-f(u)$  have the same sign.

**Theorem.** If $f\!:\ ]a,b[\>\to{\mathbb R}$ is continuous and injective then $f$ maps $\>]a,b[\>$ bijectively onto the open interval $\>]c,d[\>:=\>]\inf_{a<x<b} f(x),\sup_{a<x<b} f(x)[\>$. The inverse function $g:=f^{-1}\!:\ ]c,d[\>\to\>]a,b[\>$ is automatically continuous.

*Proof* of the last statement: WLOG we may assume that $f$ and $g$ are increasing. Consider an arbitrary point $\eta\in\>]c,d[\>$, and let $\xi:=g(\eta)\in\>]a,b[\>$. Let an arbitrary, but sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $f(\xi-\epsilon)<f(\xi)=\eta$, and $f(\xi+\epsilon)>\eta$. The open interval $U:=\>]f(\xi-\epsilon),f(\xi+\epsilon)[\>$ then is a neighborhood of $\eta$, and $g(U)\subset\>]\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon[\>$, by monotonicity.